# JavaFx Change Window, Without New Controller Constructor

Tags: java, javafx

I have 2 fxml file. Example A.fxml. B.fxml. I have 2 controller. AController (A.fxml) BController (B.fxml). A fxml and B fxml have change button changing Scene or fxml. This is button code;

```
try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/infoLibrary/view/A.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Same code in BContrroller change button. When i click change button scane changing. But everytime init method and controller contructers working too. When user change fxml javafx everytime using new constructor. How can i change windows without new controller constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a view model:

```
public class ViewModel {

    public enum View {A, B}

    private final ObjectProperty<View> currentView = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(View.A);

    public ObjectProperty<View> currentViewProperty() {
        return currentView ;
    }

    public final View getCurrentView() {
        return currentViewProperty().get();
    }

    public final View setCurrentView(View view) {
        currentViewProperty().set(view);
    }

}
```

Now in your `AController` do:

```
public class AController {

    private ViewModel viewModel ;

    public void setViewModel(ViewModel viewModel) {
        this.viewModel = viewModel ;
    }

    // button handler:
    @FXML
    private void goToB(ActionEvent event) {
        viewModel.setCurrentView(ViewModel.View.B);
    }
}
```

and `BController` is similar.

Finally, you set everything up with something like the following, which is executed only once (e.g. in your `start()` method, or somewhere similar):

```
Stage stage = ... ; // maybe it's the primary stage in start...
Scene scene = new Scene();
ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();

FXMLLoader aLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/infoLibrary/view/A.fxml"));
Parent a = aLoader.load();
AController aController = aLoader.getController();
aController.setViewModel(viewModel);

FXMLLoader bLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/infoLibrary/view/B.fxml"));
Parent b = bLoader.load();
BController bController = bLoader.getController();
bController.setViewModel(viewModel);

scene.rootProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
    if (viewModel.getCurrentView() == ViewModel.View.A) {
        return a ;
    } else if (viewModel.getCurrentView() == ViewModel.View.B) {
        return b ;
    } else {
        return null ;
    }
}, viewModel.currentViewProperty());

stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

Now the two FXML files are only loaded once (so the controllers are only created once, and their `initialize()` methods called only once). The switching is managed by changing the state of the `ViewModel` and observing that state, so the scene's root is changed when the model state changes.

Here is a complete SSCCE:

ViewModel.java:

```
package sceneswitcher;

import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;

public class ViewModel {

    public enum View {A, B}

    private final ObjectProperty<View> currentView = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(View.A);

    public ObjectProperty<View> currentViewProperty() {
        return currentView ;
    }

    public final View getCurrentView() {
        return currentViewProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setCurrentView(View view) {
        currentViewProperty().set(view);
    }

}
```

AController.java:

```
package sceneswitcher;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class AController {

    private ViewModel viewModel ;

    @FXML
    private TextField textField ;

    public void setViewModel(ViewModel viewModel) {
        this.viewModel = viewModel ;
    }

    // button handler:
    @FXML
    private void goToB(ActionEvent event) {
        viewModel.setCurrentView(ViewModel.View.B);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return textField.getText();
    }
}
```

A.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>

<VBox fx:controller="sceneswitcher.AController" spacing="5" alignment="CENTER" 
        xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

    <Label text='This is view A'/>
    <TextField fx:id="textField" />
    <Button onAction="#goToB" text="Go to view B"/>
</VBox>
```

BController.java:

```
package sceneswitcher;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

public class BController {
    private ViewModel viewModel ;

    @FXML
    private TextArea textArea ;

    public void setViewModel(ViewModel viewModel) {
        this.viewModel = viewModel ;
    }

    // button handler:
    @FXML
    private void goToA(ActionEvent event) {
        viewModel.setCurrentView(ViewModel.View.A);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return textArea.getText();
    }
}
```

B.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>

<VBox fx:controller="sceneswitcher.BController" spacing="5" alignment="CENTER"
         xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

    <Label text="This is view B"/>
    <TextArea fx:id="textArea" />
    <Button onAction="#goToA" text="Go to View A"/>
</VBox>
```

Main.java:

```
package sceneswitcher;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();

        FXMLLoader aLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("A.fxml"));
        Parent a = aLoader.load();
        AController aController = aLoader.getController();
        aController.setViewModel(viewModel);

        FXMLLoader bLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("B.fxml"));
        Parent b = bLoader.load();
        BController bController = bLoader.getController();
        bController.setViewModel(viewModel);

        Scene scene = new Scene(a, 400, 400);

        scene.rootProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
            if (viewModel.getCurrentView() == ViewModel.View.A) {
                return a ;
            } else if (viewModel.getCurrentView() == ViewModel.View.B) {
                return b ;
            } else {
                return null ;
            }
        }, viewModel.currentViewProperty()));

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do u have example project like this? Or can u write simple maven project? A fxml and B fxml AController BController. I expect too much thing, i know. But if you do it, i would be grateful.

Comment: @VolkanOkçu Updated with complete example.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am grateful for this.